# Como acceder a imagenes del servidor desde su url en Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Quiero acceder a una imagen que tenga en

`assets/images/images.jpg` o en `public/images/imagen.jpg` desde mi servidor en producción, ejemplo:

`http://miservidor.com/images/imagen.jpg`

y tenga mi imagen.

Comment: por ejemplo asi: https://www.anipedia.net/imagenes/donde-viven-los-gatos.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para mostrar imágenes que estén en directorio `public` las puedes solicitar directamente, considerando `public` como raíz; por ejemplo<sup>1</sup>:

```
<img src="/images/imagen.jpg" />
```

Para obtener la imagen directamente desde tu servidor, lo podrías hacer así (tal como lo muestras en tu ejemplo):

```
http://miservidor.com/images/imagen.jpg
```

En cambio, para mostrar imágenes que estén en `assets`, puedes utilizar el *helper* `image_tag`; por ejemplo:

```
<img src="<%= image_tag('/assets/images/image.jpg') %>" />
```

En este caso no podrías obtener la imagen a través de tu navegador como en el ejemplo anterior.

<sup>**1**</sup> Para poder ver las imágenes directamente (e.g. `http://miservidor.com/images/imagen.jpg`) debes asegurarte de tener la siguiente línea en el archivo *environments/production.rb*:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Comment: guardando mi imagen en `public/images/images.jpg` localmente puedo acceder como `localhost:3000/images/images.jpg`pero al subirlo a producción en el servidor `miservidor.com/images/images.jpg` no me deja

Comment: @andreapaolavecinopastrana Así es, guardando tu imagen en ese directorio la puedes visitar en `http://miservidor.com/images/imagen.jpg`

Comment: @andreapaolavecinopastrana ¿Te muestra algún error en el log del servidor?

Comment: ´ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/Img/aprobado.png"): actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'´

Comment: @andreapaolavecinopastrana Debes verificar la configuración en _production.rb_; mira la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Gracias Gerry era eso, me faltaba esa configuración.